# Optical path length for sound

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect

The definition of [optical path length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length) is the distance that light could have travelled in the same time, in vacuum. So, can we define something analogous for sound waves, like an "acoustical path length", with respect to a specific medium, say air?

And if we were to define something similar, how far would it's applications reach? For example, can we use it in doppler effect in cases when the observer and source are in a different media? Or interference, when there is a change of medium in between? If so, kindly guide me on how to do it.